# creating hotfixes in github

Tags: git, github

Let say I have hotfix branch(hotfix-2.0) in the github remote

Iam in my local and I want to create a brand new branch off a master and make sure it is in sync with the remote hotfix branch(hotfix-2.0) and then I want to push those changes to remote and merge those into the hotfix branch

for ex.. I have local branch feat-1.0

then when I push it to remote, it appears right next to the hotfix branch

hotfix 2.0      myfeat

can anyone tell me the process using the command line.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

These are the steps I follow for the hotfixes

Switch to master branch if your working any branch on the same repo, and pull the latest changes

```
git checkout master
git pull
```

From master create a feature branch

```
git checkout -b Hotfix-*******
```

After making changes

```
git add -A or the files you need to commit
git commit -m "commit message"
git push --set-upstream origin Hotfix-*******
```

Once the hotfix branch merged into master, then merge master to develop

```
git checkout develop
git pull
git merge --no-ff master
```

Resolve if there are any conflicts b accepting Incoming/Current changes based on your code

```
git push
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, something along the lines of:

Get the remote changes:

```
git fetch origin master
git fetch origin hotfix-2.0
```

Check out the hotfix-2.0 branch locally

```
git checkout origin/hotfix-2.0 -B hotfix-2.0
```

Merge origin/master into it

```
git merge origin/master
... fix any conflicts
git push origin hotfix-2.0
```

Create a local branch for the  hotfix-feature branch based on the current merged state

```
git checkout -B hotfix-2.0-feat
```

Merge feat-1.0 into that

```
git merge feat-1.0
... fix any conflicts
```

Push the new combined feature branch

```
git push origin hotfix-2.0-feat
```